# Vim E488: Trailing Characters in function

Tags: vim

I'm getting a trailing characters error for the 'for loop' in the following lines of code and I've no clue why.

```
function! s:HashID(str)  "{{{
    let l:hash_id = 0
    for i in split(a:str, '\zs')
        l:hash_id += float2nr(pow(2, stridx('abcdefg', i)))
    endfor
    return l:hash_id
endfunction
```

What am I goofing up here?

Comment: Upon startup. The function is called via an autocmd when the Buffer is entered. If I comment out the for loop, the error disappears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `let` command to assign value to variable.

Comment: Ah, damn damn damn. Guess it's time to call it a day